# Renamed the product name and got this error. clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I renamed the product name and run the renamed product.

At that time I got this error.
1. clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/jeevanbm/Documents/247DoctorCare iOS/247Patient/247Patient/247Patient-Prefix.pch'
2. clang: error: no input files

I renamed 247Patient to JeevanBMCare.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: When it comes to `.pch` I found out that clearing the project adn/or build folder might help. `Cmd+Options+Shift+K` will remove the build folder. `Cmd+Shift+K` will clean the project. And don't forget to close/re-open Xcode just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the name of prefix file in build setting too.

Comment: "247Patient/JeevanBMCare-Prefix.pch" Its automatically updated in prefix file header. @Sansnagar